# Not able to figure out how to find the angle of the curve.

Tags: geometry, circles, arc-length

I have these sort of curves:
[image: image of the curve]
I have tried my best but could not figure it out how to find the angle between the curve formed using the three points on curve.

I have found this reference while trying to search: 
https://www.mathopenref.com/arcradius.html
It has given the formula to find the radius of the circle formed using the three points.
I though if I get the radius then it will be easy to calculate the angle between the arcs formed using the three points. (in future more than three points.)
But there is a problem in that too.
I am not able to understand how to calculate the height of the point from the line.

The formula is:
[image: image formaula]

So this is my problem and might be very simple but I do not have a solution for that.
Can anyone suggest me how to calculate the arc angle using the three points if forming an arc or circle?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/22791951

Comment: What is "the angle of the curve" and what has it to do with the circle you are trying to find?

Comment: the phrase "the angle between the curve formed using the three points on curve" doesn't make any sense.  Are you choosing three points, then somehow using them to form a different curve, which you want to compare to the original curve?  If so, which three points, and how are you constructing the new curve?  Please clarify what you're asking.

Comment: @Milten your comment is really helpful. Thank you for your help